# Does MvcBuildViews actually do anything?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've just discovered this property in MVC projects, but I'm having a hard time determining if it has any real effect.  The following makes me believe this property has almost no real effect out of the box:

1. It does an in-place compilation of the site (AFAICT), and leaves the site "updateable" so that the markup files are not affected.  This is important for in-place compilation so the sources aren't wiped out.
2. Because it's in a WAP project, all the code files will be compiled into the project's output assembly anyways (unless they're in App_Code, but that's just odd).

So the sources in the project were already compiled, and the markup files aren't affected.  What is the actual impact of using MvcBuildViews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `<MvcBuildViews>` is set to true, building the web project results in errors if the views contain any server-side code issues. Note that this includes C# errors (compile-time / type-safety / etc.), but not JavaScript errors, as those are intrinsically non-compiled.

This feature works for **Razor** and **WebForms** views, but it seems to have no effect when the **Spark** view engine is being used.